# SQL Reference values in another table without a join

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having an issue referencing another table that cannot be joined. Table 1 has a name and value that I want to look up in table 2 and use a between case function to get the category.

In this example, I want to return:

```
Smith, 99, GOOD | Hill, 96, BAD
```

TABLE 1

```
| Name  | Number 
----------------
| Smith | 99       
| Hill  | 96    
----------------
```

TABLE 2

```
--------------------------
| Category | Min |  Max |  
--------------------------
| GOOD     | 98  | 100  |  
| BAD      | 95  | 97   |  
--------------------------
```

Comment: It's a lookup to the value ranges in table 2 I think.  What I'm not sure about is why they can't be joined.  I think you can join on a between condition here unless there's some reason that you can't join the tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You certainly can use a `JOIN`. You can use `BETWEEN` in the `ON` condition.

```
SELECT t1.name, t1.number, t2.category
ON Table1 AS t1
JOIN Table2 AS t2 ON t1.number BETWEEN t2.min AND t2.max
```

If you thought that joins could only use foreign key equality, you're mistaken.

Comment: This makes alot of sense, I will give it a try :)

Comment: What if I had a similar scenario but instead the range being between 2 columns MIN and Max, it is a column called DATE and I need to find the record i between the MIN(Date) and MAX(Date)?

Comment: You can join with a subquery: `JOIN (SELECT MIN(date) AS min, MAX(date) AS max FROM Table2) AS t2`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to answer without `join`, you can use the `Correlated SubQueries`.

```
SELECT t1.name, 
t1.number, 
(select Category from t2 where t1.number BETWEEN t2.min AND t2.max) as Category 
from  t1
```